# Laravel mail on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, smtp, shared-hosting

I've a form contact on my website and I want the form to be sent via email when submitted.

I've tried it in xampp and it's working fine.

On shared hosting, it does not work.

I'm using my own custom domain smtp.

Someone can explain me why it's not working ?

Comment: Sometimes shared hosting may require additional fields. It's a good idea to add MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS and MAIL_FROM_NAME fields to .env config

Answer (score 0):

Your shared hosting probably blocks outgoing SMTP connections. Many hosting providers do that to prevent spam. You can try using a HTTP/WEB API instead of SMTP to send email.

Some [email APIs](https://www.flutemail.com) like Flute Mail allow you to set up an HTTP API connection which can immediately forward the request through your "custom domain smtp" server. So you can keep using your custom domain email server, but get an API for it.

Otherwise you'll have to set up a Web API yourself with an open source tool like [Postal](https://github.com/atech/postal).

Answer (score 0):

In your laravel .env file if add following parameters mentioned below and create a e-mail on your shared hosting and add username, password and host of your hosting.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=shared_host_name
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@sharedhost.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I suppose then it would work fine.